# Is there a way to JOIN two tables based on a column that is modified within the query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that I would like to join based on the `_ID` field in table A and the `linked_to` field in table B.  My problem involves that fact that the values in the `linked_to` field have all been increased by 1000000000.  This means that the row with an `_ID` value of 123 needs to link to the row with a  `linked_to` value of 1000000123.  is there a way to subtract 1000000000 from the `linked_to` value within the JOIN?

edit:

I found that with a large database table (40,000+ rows) this operation takes too long to be useful (or the query caused the server to hang without explanation.)  I have not seen this operation work yet.  Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: That sounds really easy, I guess this was a case of'just try it and see.'  Are there similar techniques for string manipulation?

Comment: If it is taking too long, subtract the value from linked_to in a temp table, put an index on that column, and then perform your join.

Comment: In the end I added a new row to the database for the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming the values are integers, just do what you are saying.

```
Select _ID, linked_to FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA._ID = (TableB.linked_to - 1000000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can do arithmetic in the `join` expression:

```
select *
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a._id = b.linked_to - 1000000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do arithmetic operations in select statements. You can use +, -, /, *, change signs.
I recommend to use brackets. It's possible to subtract the value of linked_to or add the value of _id.

Two options you could try are:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA join tableB ON tableA._ID = (tableB.linked_to - 10000000000);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tableA join tableB ON (tableA._ID + 1000000000) = tableB.linked_to;
```